# How can I get the codes from the options of an attribute?

Tags: attributes, attribute-options, configurable-product-options

```
    public function getOptions($attributeCode)
    {
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
        $tmpOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($tmpOptions as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] > 0) {
                $options[] = $option;
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
```

I've the above code to get the options of an attribute, it works but it is only retrieving the labels of the options without the option codes that I stored in the database. From the below picture, I need the values EARTH, MUSHROOM, PLOW, instead of Cross Weave Earth, Cross Weave Mushroom,  and Cross Weave Plow. But the above code is only retrieving the labels, is it possible to get the codes through a native method of the EAV handler? or which is the best way to get these values in a block class and pass it to the phtml file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Getting Select values make sure you load the product store wise

```
/** Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory **/
$product = $this->productFactory->create()->setStoreId($this->storeId)->loadByAttribute('entity_id', $id);
```

just use getData('attribute_code'); on Product Object

```
$product->getData('attribute_code');
```

The above code will return the code values.

Else If you Want the Select Labels, then use the code below

```
public function getExtractedData($product, $value = '') {
        $attrValue = $product->getData($value);
        $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($value);
        if ($attr && ($attr->usesSource() || $attr->getData('frontend_input') == 'select')) {
            $labelValue = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($attrValue);
            if (is_object($labelValue)) {
                $labelValue = $labelValue->getText();
            }
            $attrValue = $labelValue;
        }
        return $attrValue;
    }
```

In the Above Function pass the ***Product Object as $product*** and ***attribute_code as $value***

Comment: Thank you Mohd, unfortunately I'm not able to rate your answer as valid, but it helped me a lot

Comment: Much appreciated, thanks